# How to delete past working directories in Octave GUI?

Tags: octave, octave-gui

Does anyone know how to delete those past working directories in Octave GUI? They are very annoying and useless.[image]

Answer (score 2):

I see from your image that you are on windows.

I don't know the equivalent directory on windows, but on linux, this information seems to be stored under ~/.config/octave/octave-gui.ini, in a section called `current_directory_list` which you can edit and clear of all unwanted entries.

See if you can find the equivalent folder where this octave-gui.ini file is stored  on windows; it may be in an AppData/Local directory, or in the octave installation folder itself...

<sub>PS: In the same directory I also had a `qt_settings` file which seems to mirror some of this information, but I think this may have been from an older octave installation.</sub>

Comment: Yes, I navigated with the command line to ~/.config/octave and then I opened the file "qt-settings" with NANO , then i edited the line "current_directory_list" , where indeed it holds those past directories. I removed unwanted directories , saved with control+O, but they are still there, but thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to deleting the file path from `octave-gui.ini`, try removing the path from `.octaverc` file as well. This will remove the warning you see at launch if the path no longer exists.